# If $a,b,c\gt 0$, prove that $\frac {a^2}{b^3 c}- \frac {a}{b^2} \ge \frac{c}{b} - \frac{c^2}{a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a,b,c\gt 0$,

$1º$ Prove that:

$$\frac {a^2}{b^3 c}- \frac {a}{b^2} \ge \frac{c}{b} - \frac{c^2}{a}$$

$2º$ For which values of $a,b,c$ the equality holds?

My try:

I tried a lot of things, but none of them worked (example):

$$\frac {a^2}{b^3 c}- \frac {a}{b^2} \ge \frac{c}{b} - \frac{c^2}{a}$$
$$\frac {a}{b^2} \left(\frac {a}{bc}-1\right)  \ge c \left(  \frac{1}{b} - \frac{c}{a} \right)$$
$$\frac {a^2b}{b^2} \left(\frac {a-bc}{bc}\right)  \ge c \left(  {a-bc} \right)$$
$$ a^2 \left(a-bc \right)  \ge b^2c^2 \left(  a-bc \right)$$
$$  a^2\ge b^2c^2$$

After this, i don't know how to proceed, and maybe it's the wrong way.

Any hints?

Comment: I don´t get it. In 1 you shaw that the inequality holds for positive numbers. Then in 2 you are tasked to find the numbers for which the inequality holds. Isn´t there a typo and it should be *equality* there?

Comment: Yes, a typo, edited thanks.

Comment: You made a small mistake. The third step should be 

$$\frac{a^2b}{b^2}\left(\frac{a-bc}{bc}\right) = c(a - bc)$$

The math works out nicely from there.

Comment: Now when dividing both sides by $(a-bc)$, remember that it’s possible that $(a-bc)$ may be positive, negative or zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $a/c^2$, and write the result as

$$\left(a\over bc\right)^3-\left(a\over bc\right)^2\ge{a\over bc}-1$$

Now let $x={a\over bc}$ and note that

$$x^3-x^2\ge x-1\iff x^3-x^2-x+1\ge0\iff(x-1)^2(x+1)\ge0\iff x+1\ge0$$

Since $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all assume to be positive, $x\gt0$, which implies $x+1\ge0$, so the inequality is proved.

The *equality* clearly holds when $x=1$ (i.e., when $x-1=0$), which is to say when $a=bc$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Consider the expression
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a-bc)^2(a+bc) \geq 0.
\end{eqnarray*}